# How to check an exact match in a join table

Tags: sql, db2

Let's consider the following problem :

- Table 'Picture' with id, title, size.
- Table 'Color' with id, label.
- A join table 'Pic_Col' with picture_id, color_id
- Each picture has 1 to n color

I'm trying to find in SQL (DB2 but I'm curious about other RDBMS capabilities) a way to return something that would answer the following questions :

- One query for :

  > Does the picture with id X contains only blue and yellow ?
- One query for :

  > Does the picture with id Y contains at least blue and yellow ?
  >
  > Does the picture with id Z contains at least blue and yellow but no red ?

I would like to provide as parameters : id of picture, list of wanted colors, list of unwanted colors.

The only solutions I managed to find are based on `EXISTS` with sub-queries or X joins (X being the number of color in the query) and aggregation (`CASE WHEN`etc)...

```
    SELECT 1
    FROM 
        picture p
    WHERE
        p.id = 123
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM pic_col pc
                INNER JOIN color c ON (c.id = pc.color_id AND c.label = 'blue')
            WHERE
                pc.picture_id = p.id
        )
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM pic_col pc
                INNER JOIN color c ON (c.id = pc.color_id AND c.label = 'yellow')
            WHERE
                pc.picture_id = p.id
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM pic_col pc
                INNER JOIN color c ON (c.id = pc.color_id AND c.label = 'red')
            WHERE
                pc.picture_id = p.id
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I like conditional aggregation for this purpose.

> Does the picture with id X contains only blue and yellow ?

```
select picture_id
from pic_col pc join
     colors c
     on pc.color_id = c.id
group by picture_id
having count(*) = sum(case when c.label in ('blue', 'yellow')
```

> Does the picture with id Y contains at least blue and yellow ?

```
select picture_id
from pic_col pc join
     colors c
     on pc.color_id = c.id
group by picture_id
having sum(case when c.label = 'blue' then 1 else0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when c.label = 'yellow' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

> Does the picture with id Z contains at least blue and yellow but no red ?

```
select picture_id
from pic_col pc join
     colors c
     on pc.color_id = c.id
group by picture_id
having sum(case when c.label = 'blue' then 1 else0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when c.label = 'yellow' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when c.label = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) =  0;
```

The `having` clause is adding up the number of matches for each color (or groups of colors) for each picture.  The `> 0` is saying that the color is present.  The `= 0` is saying that the color is not present.

Comment: Every solution means building the query dynamically. Is there a way to only give an array as parameter ?

Comment: @Darnoj . . . DB2 doesn't support array parameters, as far as I know.  I think this answers the question that you asked in this question.  If you have another question, then ask it as another question.